# where can I find the proof of this theorem of wavelet frames?

Tags: harmonic-analysis, wavelets

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a [local field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_field).

> **Definition of local field:**
>
> Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and a topological space. Then $\mathbb{K}$ is called a *locally compact field* if both $\mathbb{K}^+$ and $\mathbb{K}^*$ are locally compact Abelian groups, where $\mathbb{K}^+$ and $\mathbb{K}^*$ denote the additive and multiplicative groups of $\mathbb{K}$, respectively.
>
> a ***local field*** is a locally compact field with respect to a non-discrete topology.

For given $\Psi:=\left \{ \psi_{1},...,\psi_{L} \right \}\subset L^{2}(\mathbb{K})$, define the wavelet system

$X(\Psi ):=\left \{ \psi_{l,j,k}:1\leq l\leq L;j\in \mathbb{Z},k\in \mathbb{N}_{0} \right \}$
where $\psi_{j,k}^{l}=q^{\frac{j}{2}}\psi^{l}(\rho ^{j}.-u(k))$. ($q$ and $\rho$ is fixed.)

the wavelet system $X(\Psi )$ is called a Parseval wavelet frame if
$\sum_{l=1}^{L}\sum_{j\in \mathbb{Z}}\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}_{0}}\left | \left \langle f,\psi_{l,j,k} \right \rangle \right |^{2}=\left \| f \right \|^{2},  \forall f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{K}) $

---

**Theorem.** Let $X(\Psi)$ be Parseval wavelet frame. then every $f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{K})$ can be written as

$f(x)=\sum_{l=1}^{L}\sum_{j\in \mathbb{Z}}\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}_{0}}\left \langle f,\psi_{l,j,k}  \right \rangle\psi_{l,j,k}(x)$

Comment: hence $X(\Psi)$ is called a Parseval wavelet frame iff $f \to \langle\Psi,f\rangle $ is a unitary transformation ! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_operator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a property that holds for any Parseval frame. The following is just a special case:

> Note that, for all $f \in L^2 (\mathbb{K})$,
>   $$ \langle f, f  \rangle = \sum_{l=1}^{L}\sum_{j\in \mathbb{Z}}\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}_{0}} \langle f,\psi_{l,j,k} \rangle \langle \psi_{l,j,k},f \rangle \ $$
>   whenever the wavelet system $X (\Psi)$ forms a Parseval frame for $L^2 (\mathbb{K})$. Therefore, 
>   $$ 
> 0 = \langle f, f  \rangle - \sum_{l=1}^{L}\sum_{j\in \mathbb{Z}}\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}_{0}} \langle f,\psi_{l,j,k} \rangle \langle \psi_{l,j,k},f \rangle \ = \bigg\langle f - \sum_{l=1}^{L}\sum_{j\in \mathbb{Z}}\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}_{0}} \langle f,\psi_{l,j,k} \rangle \psi_{l,j,k}, \;f \bigg\rangle $$
>   for all $f \in L^2 (\mathbb{K})$, and hence
>   $$ f = \sum_{l=1}^{L}\sum_{j\in \mathbb{Z}}\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}_{0}} \langle f,\psi_{l,j,k} \rangle \psi_{l,j,k}. $$